# React components styling dilemma

Tags: css, inline-styles, css-modules, radium

I start making new project using React and Redux. I'm new to React and not sure about what kind of styling mehtod I should use. Apparently I want to use the one that will not decrease performance, give all features of CSS3, and be maintainable. So the choices are:

1. Inline styling using **Radium**
2. **SASS**
3. **CSS Modules**

I've long experience working with SASS and CSS3.Nevertheless **Inline Styling** really impressed me but it does not provide autoprefixer and some other nice automation features.
Obviously there's no ultimate choice, but what is the most efficient one?

Comment: Personally I use CSS Modules + SASS, but there's one more approach (than you've pointed out).
Styled components: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/01/styled-components-enforcing-best-practices-component-based-systems/

As I don't know much about styled components I just gave you an article.
What I can tell about SASS + CSS Modules is that they're really good, beacuse you've got best of 2 worlds (inline / css):
- modularisation (no more conflicts)
- easier code completion / support for classical SASS / CSS

Comment: You have many many more options than that (for better or for worse). I've been using glamor and find it much less buggy than Radium https://github.com/threepointone/glamor. khan academy's aphrodite library is also very good https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite

Comment: I’m using Sass + CSS Modules right now. It’s a good choice for projects that already use Sass or for teams that are familiar with Sass. I also have some experience with JSS and CSS Modules + cssnext (PostCSS preset) — I like both but both have their own pros and cons. I’ve also heard a lot of good about Styled Components but haven’t had an opportunity to try them.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally recommend a combination of [glamor](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor) and [glamorous](https://github.com/paypal/glamorous). Glamorous is build on glamor so you can leverage both for different purposes.

With glamor, you can inject global styles into the page like:

```
css.global('h1', { fontSize: '3rem' })
```

With glamorous, you can create React components that make styling things more intuitive, like:

```
glamorous.Div({ padding: '2rem', background: 'red' })

return <Div>Some text</Div>
```

Personally I prefer to use CSS-in-JS versus a pre-processor like Sass/LESS or using some sort of CSS-like tool. I find trying to write CSS in a template tag or in another file is cumbersome and annoying. Leveraging JavaScript directly for styling is actually quite enjoyable once you get used to it.

**Shameless plug:** I've created a helper library for CSS-in-JS project that automatically generates helpful styling classes like what you find in Bootstrap (eg `.text-center`, `.ml-auto`, `.display-block` etc). It's called [Euphoria](https://github.com/danawoodman/euphoria), check it out!